# How to set the position of a label in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to improvise a chat for my web site. I have 2 TextBoxes (one for the subject of the question and other for the content of the question). After a certain button is clicked I update a Label with the results.

The position of the Label is not where I want it to be. How can I adjust the position of the Label?

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? WinForms? Silverlight? WPF?

Comment: Adding to ColinE's comment, please take the time to read the tags you're adding: "Graphical User Interface development for applications or web sites. This tag should usually be combined with other tags specifying the programming language, platform or framework, if applicable." =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds%28v=vs.80%29) of the label to change it's position & size (assuming your referring to WinForms). Alternatively you can set the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.80%29) property directly.

Comment: @Katerina I didn't downvote your question, it would be a bit contradicting to downvote & answer. I just gave your question an up-vote (as I don't like people who -1 without stating why). To answer your question though, probably because you didn't provide enough information in your question for others to go on. Even with my answer I had to assume you were using WinForms.

Comment: I'm trying to improvise a chat for my web site in c#, .net framework 4.0. I have 2 TextBox-es (one for the subject of the question and other for the content of the question). After a certain button is click (button "Ask Question") I like to put the content and the subject into Label text. I put them, but the position of the Label is not where I want it to be.

Comment: @Katerina - I would advise updating your question with that information. Again though, you haven't stated which UI Framework you are using e.g. Silverlight/WPF/WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Location` property to set the location of your label on your form.

Comment: @Katerina I din't down vote you , for me it was a beginer's question , except you din't mention what is your framework i.g. WinForm , WPF etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textblock_name.Margin = new Thickness(338, 57, 0, 0);

        }
```

you can use above code to change position dynamically